# Jackson cant instantiate ArrayList

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-boot

I want to send the following POST request:

```
POST: /api/test
{
   "words": ["running", "testing", "and"]
}
```

My controller looks as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/api/test"}, method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Text> getWords(@RequestBody Words words) {
    // Do something with words...
    return new ResponseEntity<Text>(new Text("test"), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The Words class:

```
public class Words {

    private List<String> words;

    public Words(List<String> words) {
        this.words = words;
    }

    public List<String> getWords() {
        return words;
    }
}
```

When sending Strings instead of the List it works fine however with the List I get the following error:

```
Could not read document:
No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class api.models.tokenizer.Words]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@60f2a08; line: 2, column: 5]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class api.models.tokenizer.Words]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@60f2a08; line: 2, column: 5]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default Jackson creates instance of class using default constructor. You do not have one. So, either add constructor

```
public Words() {}
```

Or mark existing constructor using annotation `@JsonCreator`:

```
@JsonCreator
public Words(@JsonProperty("words") List<String> words) {
    this.words = words;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.
But isn't the default constructor automatically generated when not declared? For example calling `Words words = new Words();` works even without explicitly declaring the default constructor. Why is Jackson not using this generated default constructor?

Comment: Default constructor is automatically generated only if no other constructor is defined. Otherwise you have to define it explicitly.